# application works locally but not on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

i have created an application, it works perfectly fine on my system but when i deploy it on azure app service. it doesn't work. it is showing such error.
An error occurred while starting the application.

.NET Core 4.6.27817.03 X86 v4.0.0.0 | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.2.0-rtm-35687    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393    |   Need help?

i have tried to check the azure app service platform, but it is fine. 
Also i have tried to check the publish settings on the visual studio.

Under the 'Entity framework Migrations' dropdown in publish settings i see this error:

Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.

Possible reasons for this include:

You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.

You intended to execute a NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.

You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

Also i have checked everything, it looks fine. 
I have tried to create a fresh new .net core 2.2 project and tried to deploy it but that also shows the same issues.

i want it to be deployed on azure and in working condition.

Whoever can, kindly Help.

Comment: If you're getting EF errors: is there a database context that's trying to update a database? And if there is.... is the database there and available? And is the connectionstring to the database set correctly?
We need some more information on your application and how it is set up to be able to help. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Agree with @rickvdbosch. It is tough to troubleshoot with what's given above.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the below answer for troubleshooting issue around dot net core 2.2

[ASP.NET Core 2.2 App Service hosted on Azure returning 500 without an exception being thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893625/asp-net-core-2-2-app-service-hosted-on-azure-returning-500-without-an-exception)

This will give you the actual reason of the error which you can use it to resolve.

Additionally , you can enable DetailedErrorsKey in the Program.cs so you can figure it out what's happening.

For startup related exception , you can take look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#startup-exception-handling) link.

The Database Error Page `**middleware**` captures database-related exceptions that can be resolved by using Entity Framework migrations. When these exceptions occur, an HTML response with details of possible actions to resolve the issue is generated. This page should be enabled only in the Development environment. Enable the page by adding code to Startup.Configure:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#database-error-page

Hope it helps.